# ASP.Net MVC run JavaScript in PartialView when loaded using Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, partial-views

I've got a question regarding ASP.Net MVC.

I'm using an Ajax.ActionLink to load a PartialView.

In this partial view is a javascript function I'd like to get called.

However I can't figure out how to make this happen.

I've tried using AjaxOptions { OnSuccess="functionInPartialView" } when I set the Ajax.ActionLink but for some reason it can't see the Javascript.

EDIT: The PartialView is a mix of JavaScript and Html

Comment: what do you mean that you can't see the javascript. It's not rendering in the page , or it is not called.

Comment: It's not being called. I've tried many different ways of trying to get it to fire. The only way that I found worked was to load the PartialView using a jquery ajax call

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest to use jQuery ($.get/$.ajax). It evaluates the $(function(){}) when you load the partial, so your scripts there fire. And I personally find jQuery easier and cleaner to use.

Comment: yup, you're right. I've ended up resorting to this and it works sweet. cheers

Answer (score 5):

Add the javascript code in the view that will contain the parcialview, and next use the ajaxOptions { OnSuccess="**functionInView**" } when you set the Ajax.ActionLink.

Answer (score 3):

If it's only javascript in your partial view, then you should be using a JavaScript Action result, as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312408/asp-net-mvc-javascript-actionresult)

Otherwise, the issue is that ajax merely loading content into a div doesn't mean that it executes.  In your ajax callback, you need to find the javascript content and eval it, so that your page is aware of the function definition.

I know that's a high level description, but I don't have any samples of doing this.  If you post some of the code, maybe someone can suggest a cleaner way of doing this so that you have better access to the script.

Comment: unfortunately it's not only javascript. Sorry I should have made that more clear

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Multipartials](http://pulzonic.com/multipartial) , you can use them to update multiple views and even run scripts from partials, im not sure about the exact specifics as its been a while, but you can have a look at it and see if it can accomplish what you are looking for