# ASP .net MVC - Alert using Javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC. I was using javascript alert in previous application from coding. How to give an alert from Controller?

Comment: Here is an example of using JavascriptResult: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312408/asp-net-mvc-javascript-actionresult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you could just have your controller set a boolean flag in ViewData and have your view render a script tag with the alert statement if that boolean flag is true.